# Can i get married without my dads consent

Tags: nikah, wali, consent

I don’t have any issues with my dad, i want him to be there and all that but I don’t want his consent to get married, or any man’s. I find it incredibly misogynistic, my consent is the only consent that matters. So when i get married can i do it without my father’s or any man’s consent.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Be aware that the consent of scholars is that a marriage of an inexperienced woman can't get married by her own and the formal agreement of her guardian is necessary for nikah being valid.

Answer (score 2):

Of the four madhabs, Hanafi allows some leeway here while the other three require the consent of your wali. Regarding Hanafi, https://daruliftaa.com/nikah-marriage/does-the-hanafi-school-encourage-marriage-without-the-guardians-approval/ covers the details better than i could, alhamdulilah.

Bear in mind this is Allah's law. I would advise against thinking badly of it like you alude to in your wording. You should be happy, for He knows what's best for us and only means good for us. I encourage you to read that link with an open mind to see the wisdom behind this condition.